# Classification of critical points for plane autonomous system

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Okay so I've changed the 2nd order nonlinear ODE

$$
x'' = a(x')^2 - ax' -ax
$$
where a is a real constant,

into
$$
x' = y
$$
$$
y' = ay^2 -ay - ax
$$

I'm asked to verify the critical point (0,0). Thats easy and done.

The problem is now how to place the transformed system into matrix form so i can determine eigenvalues etc.... How do I work with the term
$$
y^2
$$

???

Am I meant to use some other means to classify the critcal point?

Comment: You don't. For the eigenvalues you consider the linearized system, and in $(0,0)$ the term $y^2$ gives no contribution.

Comment: Okay great. Just for clarity, whenever a nonlinear term appears in the linearized system then I must simply ignore that term and create a matrix with the remaining linear terms?

Comment: The linearized system has, by the meaning of its name, no non-linear terms. But yes, you can insert $(x,y)=(x_0+\Delta x,y_0+\Delta y)$ and ignore all terms of higher order than 1 in $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ to obtain the linearized system. The other, more direct, way is the computation of the Jacobian in $(x_0,y_0)$..